Is explicit specialization of a class template via a using alias supposed to work?
Fist of all, what I'm doing seems to work on all of GCC/Clang/MSVC/icc/etc, so my question is; is that by accident or does the standard require it to be allowed?
In one way it seems like a logical extension of stuff, but on the other hand the syntax just looks strange enough that I'm concerned I'm wondering off into depending-on-bugs territory:
#include <type_traits>

template <int, bool>
void Bar();

template <int i>
struct A {
    struct T : std::true_type {};
    static void Foo() { Bar<i, T::value>(); }
};

// The normal way to do thing:
template <> struct A<1>::T : std::false_type {};

// But this also seems to work despite looking very odd:
using A3 = A<3>;
template <> struct A3::T : std::false_type {};

void Go() {
    A<0>::Foo();  // Calls Bar<0, true>()
    A<1>::Foo();  // Calls Bar<1, false>()
    A<2>::Foo();  // Calls Bar<2, true>()
    A<3>::Foo();  // Calls Bar<3, false>()
}


I wouldn't use this because of worse code readability regardless of whether it's supposed to work or not

@AntonMalyshev In general, maybe, But assume for the question that A<3> is some huge mouthful of a type that needs to be referred to in multiple places, is expected to get edited at some point and failing to have them all match would be "very bad".

It is ill-formed.
See [temp.spec.general]/3:

In an explicit specialization declaration for [...] a member of a class template [...] the variable or class that is explicitly specialized shall be specified with a simple-template-id.

A3 is not a simple-template-id.

And yet I wonder how many compilers allow it? Ouch.

@BCS I don't know. The rule has been there since C++98 and I can't find any matching bug reports for either GCC or Clang.

A3 is not a simple-template-id because it aliases A<3> which is not a simple-template-id, correct?

@Oersted simple-template-id is a grammar rule. It should be a template-name followed by <, optionally followed by a comma-separated list of optional template arguments, followed by >. The token sequence (or rather single token) A3 doesn't satisfy this because there is no < or > in it and because A3 isn't a template-name. The fact that A3 is a type alias is irrelevant.

thx. I thought that 9.2.3.8 allowed for an alias to be a simple-template-id if it aliased such an id. I may have misunderstood.

@Oersted The numbering in the standard is not stable. It is better to refer to the tag given to sections and to mention which draft or standard you are referring to.

@Oersted I assume you meant something in [dcl.typedef], but I don't see anything in there which I can associate without your comment.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.typedef#8 I can't quite wrap my head around this wording: A simple-template-id is only a typedef-name if its template-name names an alias template

@Oersted You can see above that the production rule for typedef-name is either identifier or simple-template-id. So generally wherever the grammar expects a typedef-name you can also write a simple-template-id. Your quote clarifies however that this is only true if the template-name part of the simple-template-id is an alias template, i.e. if it is written for example A<T1> where A is an alias template rather than e.g. a class template. This is not only a semantic requirement, but something that the parser needs to check to decide whether the production rule can be applied.

@Oersted But the quote in my answer says that in a declaration of an explicit specialization of a member of a class template only a simple-template-id can be used to name the specialized class. Just an identifier, which could be valid as a template-name in a nested-name-specifier that is used to specify what the explicit specialization specializes, is not semantically valid although the grammar permits it syntactically.
